# Sharepoint 2007 webpart with dll in gac fails

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

I've got a custom webpart in Sharepoint 2007 that works when used on the same machine sharepoint is installed on. When I browse to the page from a remote machine, the webpart renders but when you click the submit button, I get redirected to /_layouts/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=

Does anyone have any idea what is happening, or what I should do?

Comment: What is the submit button supposed to do? Where does it redirect to when you test it on the server? Sounds like a problem with permissions.

Comment: Yes, I do think it is permissions now. The webpart is adding a new contact to a list and redirecting the user to the home page. I've commented out the list update method and it works. So now I've got to figure out how to allow the anonymous user to edit the list, I guess?

Comment: you could impersonate the user with SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can view the setting to enable annymous access here:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/enable-anonymous-access-HA010113018.aspx

Comment: Yes,thanks. I was using SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivleges incorrectly. I was getting the list through SPContext.Current.Site which makes the privilege elevation useless. You have to create a new reference to the site and web using the ID property of the current site. Thanks all!